# How to install jar file of the program of Code_2_UML

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

I want to convert classes to UML (class diagram) by [Code_2_UML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/code2uml/). I downloaded its jar file. Now the question is how to install this jar file into the eclipse one time for all projects to use **program of Code_2_UML that is a UML class generator** add-on for eclipse?

Note: The question is not converting jar file to UML, but question is to how to install jar file of Code_2_UML program into eclipse.

btw, I don't prefer to use [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/), because the quality of diagrams after converting to image to print diagram is low and in case of multiplicity of classes output will be unreadable.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding in my question. I edited my question.

Comment: This is much better. +1 and I am removing the previous comment.